# Ubuntu stuck on blank boot up screen, neglected to make a back up. Can I back up files from live usb?

Tags: live-usb, backup, restore

As the title suggests, I failed to make a back up for my ubuntu system. 
I have been using a bootable SSD for ubuntu over the last several months and I do most of my day to day on the SSD.

The issue began when I was using virtualbox to boot up a Kali VM. It failed to boot and then when I went to restart virtual box, I was met with an insufficient permissions message. I forgot what the message entailed exactly but it was something i hadn’t seen before.

Whatever, so I went to reboot my machine and when I did, I was met with a blank purple(ubuntu’s color) screen. No options to boot into GRUB.

I am able to see and access files off the SSD when I booted into the live cd so I was wondering if I could back up and recover the files if I were to do a reinstallation.

P.S. When I enter the installation process from the live CD I don’t have the reinstallation option.

```
Model: ATA APPLE HDD ST750L (scsi) 
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B 
Partition Table: gpt 
Disk Flags: 

Number Start  End Size File system Name Flags 
1      20.5kB 210MB    210MB fat32 EFI system partition boot, esp 
2      210MB  750GB    749GB Macintosh HD 
3      750GB  750GB    650MB hfs+ Recovery HD


Model: WD My Passport 25F3 (scsi) 
Disk /dev/sdb: 512GB 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B 
Partition Table: gpt 
Disk Flags: 

Number Start End Size File system Name Flags 
1 1049kB 8591MB 8590MB linux-swap(v1) 
2 8591MB 511GB 502GB ext4 
3 511GB 512GB 1000MB hfs+ 

Untitled Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, 
but the backup appears OK, so that will be used. OK/Cancel?
```

Comment: Do you have a separate Home partition? If so, are the files you want to back-up all contained within it. If not where are they located?

Comment: @PaulBenson All of my files are on the SSD. Someone on a different thread suggested that I make a separate partition on the drive.

Comment: I know the files are on your SSD, but that's not what I was asking. I think the best way to get to an answer is for you to run command `sudo parted -l` from Live Ubuntu, post output into your question and we'll take it from there.

Comment: This is very difficult to read. That's why I asked you to post into your question. All you had to do was paste the output from the terminal into your question and enclose it with braces. Then one could read line by line. So do you know offhand which partition/s/disks your files are stored on? Looks like sdb2 is most likely with sdb3 as a possibility. Also the GPT for disk sdb (Linux) is corrupted. That's why you're having issues.

Comment: @PaulBenson Hey Paul, I'm sorry about that. Obviously new to this community, trying my best. Cleaned the code up and you can now see it in the post as you requested. To reiterate my initial question, now that we confirmed that the drive is corrupt, is there a way I can restore files from the drive? I have an external drive coming in on Wednesday.

Comment: Just about anything worth restoring is in the home directory. you should/might be able to copy or rsync this using a Live USB.

Comment: @David Ehnstrom That looks a lot better. Are these data files you wish to back-up? I'm a little confused because you start by saying you failed to backup your **system**, then later say you were wondering if you could recover 'files' on re-installation which suggests it's the **data files** you want to back up. Please clarify. I'm assuming if that's the case these data files will be on sdb2.

Comment: @PaulBenson I guess all that I am trying to do is back up the files, yes. I was wondering how I would go about recovering those files and restoring them on the reinstallation. I have run into permission errors but I have also been told that I just need to `sudo cp file.name /new_drive`. If that's wrong information please advise me correctly. Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate this!